# usage of "if" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> if you would all like to collect your books from the back.

Is that mean just "take your books from the back?" then why he uses "if"?

I wonder when I use "if", then I have to add more sentence like "you can" in this.

> if you would like to come my party, **you can.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a polite form, it is an invitation to do something rather than an instruction or an order. The sentence has an implicit completion of "... then we can begin, if you do not then we will waste time". For example, children in a school lesson will be instructed to get their books. Adults at a voluntary event will be invited to get their books.

For the "party" sentance, the wording suggests that the person was not originally invited but having learnt about the party, they asked the host who said "you can [come to the party], if you want to".

A similar sounding sentance would be "if you would like to come my party, you can enjoy some wonderful music." That is an example of the party host explaining a benefit of coming, perhaps to someone who originally declined the invitation.

Comment: Your last example does not sound correct to this native Brit. The ideas seem like a non-sequitur. "If you come to my party, you can/will enjoy some wonderful music." The enjoyment of the music is not dependent upon the "liking" to come, it is dependent upon the "actual" coming. "If you would like to come to my party, then you may -- and if you *do* come, you'll hear some awesome music!"

Comment: @PrimeMover I am also native British. Thanks for that thought. Perhaps the word "like" is unnecessary or even wrong in that example. I will think some more and maybe adjust the example.

Comment: You also might want to correct the spelling. I would do, but I would need to change at least 6 characters, and there are only 2 I want to change.